Why can't I start an AVD from a remote IntelliJ session using Jetbrains Gateway?
At work I am currently working on a Jetpack Compsoe App. For that I use a Linux workstation with Android Studio.
My team does a lot of remote work and for that we mainly use Jetpack Gateway. With all the plugins I have Intellij setup nearly the same as Android Studio and basically everything is working, I can fully build the project etc.
However I am unable to start any AVDs - Within Intellij I only get the error
The emulator process for AVD xxx has terminated

The cause for the crash as per the logs is:
  2024-09-06 09:45:20,115 [1060186]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - /home/xxx/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -studio-params /tmp/emu1163.tmp -avd Medium_Phone_API_33 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,121 [1060192]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Storing crashdata in: /tmp/xxx/emu-crash-35.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 604199
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,121 [1060192]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Android emulator version  (build_id 12234392) (CL:N/A)
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,121 [1060192]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Graphics backend: gfxstream
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,121 [1060192]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Found systemPath /home/xxx/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,192 [1060263]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Storing crashdata in: /tmp/xxx/emu-crash-35.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 604199
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,192 [1060263]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,192 [1060263]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Warning: could not connect to display  ((null):0, (null))
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,192 [1060263]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Warning: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin. ((null):0, (null))
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,192 [1060263]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/xxx/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins" even though it was found. ((null):0, (null))
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,192 [1060263]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,192 [1060263]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - 
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,192 [1060263]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, xcb, offscreen, vnc.
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,192 [1060263]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - ((null):0, (null))
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,192 [1060263]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,193 [1060264]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - 
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,193 [1060264]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Available platform plugins are: linuxfb, minimal, xcb, offscreen, vnc.
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,193 [1060264]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - ((null):0, (null))
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,195 [1060266]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - [604209:604209:20240906,094520.195070:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,195 [1060266]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - [604209:604209:20240906,094520.195394:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,196 [1060267]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - [604209:604209:20240906,094520.196244:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
    2024-09-06 09:45:20,196 [1060267]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - [604209:604209:20240906,094520.196249:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:75] read out of range
    2024-09-06 09:45:21,267 [1061338]   INFO - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT)
    2024-09-06 09:45:21,267 [1061338]   WARN - Emulator: Medium Phone API 33 - Emulator terminated with exit code 13435.1.20.0

I've tried for a while and can't find a fix. As the logs suggest I assume, that the main reason is that, no proper screen can be found, but that doesn't really help me fix anything.
Among other things I've tried:

Reinstalling emulator/sdk
Manually executing the command
Making sure libxcb-cursor0 are installed/in the lib directory of the emulator

Things that do work:

Starting the emulator via a X11 Server, but then it's really slow

Furthermore I was also unable to start the emulator on a VNC server - on the VNC viewer I only see that the emulator crashed. Any help would be massively appreciated!
